# Fixing a CSL file that fails to print the date correctly in pandoc

Tags: citations, bibtex, pandoc

I am having a minor but very irritating problem with pandoc and citations.  In accordance with Pandoc's [User Guide](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) I insert the citation like this:

```
[@ChandrajitBanerjee12]
```

The applicable Bibtex reference is:

```
@article-newspaper{ChandrajitBanerjee12,
title        = {{Necessary for Growth}},
author       = {Chandrajit Banerjee},
journal      = {Business Line},
month        = {13 October},
year         = {2012}`
```

I use [this CSL file from Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/styles/chicago-fullnote-bibliography).

As per the User Guide, I give the command:

```
pandoc --bibliography ./references.bib --csl my-documents/chicago-fullnote-bibliography.csl -o /tmp/stuff.odt /tmp/stuff.txt
```

What I get is the following in a footnote, which is correct:

Chandrajit Banerjee, “Necessary for Growth,” *Business Line* (13 October 2012)

But in the main references I get this:

Banerjee, Chandrajit. “Necessary for Growth.” *Business Line*

What happened to the date?

I presume this is a problem in the CSL file.  But I can't make head or tail out of [the CSL specification given here](http://citationstyles.org/downloads/specification-csl10-20100530.html) so I can't figure out what needs to be fixed.

Or would this be a problem in Pandoc?  Am totally confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And now we have agreement: it's the CSL files.

http://forums.zotero.org/discussion/27961/chicago-styles-no-year-in-bibliography/

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much for following this up.  I didn't have access to a computer much for the last few days so couldn't respond earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem. I don't think it's the CSL file. I used the Chicago CSL files with Zotero as a test: it puts the dates in the bibliography entries properly. So I think the problem is more likely to lie with pandoc. That's not a solution, but it might help you to find one.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a bug report at the [citeproc-hs](http://code.google.com/p/citeproc-hs/) project site.

The developer is quite sure that the problem lies with the CSL files, as you originally suspected.

He also identified a version of the CSL file that works properly with pandoc. For the specific style I'm using, chicago-note-biblio-no-ibid, the last working version seems to be from January 2012.

So perhaps if you go through the older versions of the file you're using until you get to January 2012, you'll get a CSL file that works with pandoc.